# Doubt regarding work function and photoelectric current

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photoelectric-effect

The cathode of a photoelectric cell is changed such that work function changes from W1 to W2.(W2>W1)
If photoelectric current before and after the change are I1 and I2 respectively, then I1 < or = or > I2?. (Given hf>W2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [photoelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect) has the work function as a limit on the frequency of the light . Here is a table on the work function of [various metals.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/photoelec.html) You see that the differences are  not very large . [Photons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon#Physical_properties) have to have at least the energy in the table , ( E=h*nu, nu the frequency)

The effect of changing the lower limit of the frequency that can be accepted to excite a photoelectron depends on the incident light spectrum. It may have *no effect* on the current , or a *small effect* from the edge of the spectrum not having enough energy to excite as many photoelectrons as some other material.

In your question, if W2 is larger than W1 then I2 may be a bit smaller than W1 as part of the spectrum will not excite any photoelectrons.